# Skip first rown with read-excel-file/node

Tags: node.js

I have excell files that have the first line empty and the headers start from the second line.

Is there a way to skip the first one and start from the second one when reading the file with read-excel-file/node?

I would expect to be able to skip the first line.. The "skip empty lines" option is on by default but it doesn't seem to apply to those before the headers.